# What's wrong with this nearest neighbor interpolation shader?

Tags: algorithm

GPU.js converts a JS func into a shader. The following function knows `this.thread.x` as the current index being operated on, but it is ultimately working as a WebGL shader.

```
export default function(sprite, w, h, scale) {
  var bufferWidth = w * 4;
  var channel = this.thread.x % 4;
  var thread = this.thread.x - channel;
  var y = Math.round(this.thread.x / bufferWidth);
  var x = (thread % bufferWidth) / 4;
  var upscale = scale * 10;
  var upscaleY = y * 10;
  var upscaleX = x * 10;
  var scaledY = Math.round(upscaleY / upscale);
  var scaledX = Math.round(upscaleX / upscale);
  var newIndex = scaledY * bufferWidth + scaledX * 4;
  if (x <= w * scale && y <= h * scale) {
    return sprite[newIndex + channel];
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

This almost works, but rows become skipped completely, actually making the result shorter than it should, and lines where those missing rows travel up and down and left to right on the image as it's scaled over time.

You can see this effect here: https://enviziion.github.io/lost-worlds/

What's wrong with my algo? Ive tried tweaking rounding and all sorts of stuff but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.floor when computing y:

```
var y = Math.floor(thread / bufferWidth);
```

If you use Math.round then it will start rounding up to the next row halfway across the buffer, which will produce a weird discontinuity.

Mathematically, you should be able to get back thread.x from y * bufferWidth + x * 4, which works for floor but not round.

Comment: This doesnt seem to be the solution. I had originally used floor for everything, and I just swapped it back to floor for that line only and the discontinuity persists.

Comment: Why do you multiply by 10? Isn't it just going to cancel out?

Comment: I did it to solve for the new location, as per the answer to this question, which I also asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912609/a-is-b-times-x-how-do-i-solve-for-this Edit: Actually the multiply by 10 solution was in the comments, not the answer.

Comment: Try a different device, it seems to render fine on my phone.